# Ubuntu freezing after updating GPU drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, freeze

When using Ubuntu I frequently have my whole laptop freezing. Nothing will work apart from rebooting the system. This only happens whenever I have updated my GPU drivers to any of the proprietary drivers (so this does not happen with the below stated driver). To use the full potential of the laptop, and to speed up coding, I want to use my GPU, but for that I need to update by drivers. In the attached screenshot I have tried multiple proprietary drivers (525, 515 and 470 metapackage) all resulting in the OS freezing. I have tried multiple times to reinstall Ubuntu, all having the same behavior.

List of available drivers:

[image: Full list of available drivers]

- Model: HP ZBook Studio G5 laptop
- CPU: Nvidia Quadro P1000 Mobile
- CPU: Intel Core i7-8750H
- RAM: 8 GB
- OS: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (with a dual boot Windows 10)
- GPU Drivers: X.Org X server - Nouveau display driver from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau (open source)

Comment: Given that I am really new to Ubuntu, I am not sure at all. Can you maybe specify/clarify what you mean exactly?

What I have tried so far is installing the above mentioned drivers from the additional drivers screen (the same screenshot)

Comment: To install the correct drivers, just run `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` and then reboot after the installation is complete. After a reboot and when you go back to the tab with the installed drivers, Do not switch to nouveau and do use the one that is listed as recommended (probably will be selected by default after the installation).

Comment: I just ran the ```sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall``` command, which installed "NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-525 (proprietary)". It is now, however, freezing again, whereas the nouveau driver does not have this problem